# Are there any good sql books that you can buy online

Tags: sql, sql-server

Are there any good sql books that you can buy online.

Comment: How could you get this short username?

Comment: What's a "CPU query"? A query that only uses CPU (no I/O)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of anywhere these user level statistics are logged by default, but you could log them yourself. Most people only care about CPU issues (when it's strained, etc) and identifying *what* is causing this. One of the most popular scripts to identify this is [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/) by Adam Machanic. There are, naturally, many paid solutions like [Red-Gate](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-monitor/index), [SenturyOne](https://www.sentryone.com/), [SolarWinds](https://www.solarwinds.com/), etc...

You'll need to pay close attention to [how to capture the output](http://whoisactive.com/docs/25_capturing/) for logging this to a table. Also, by default the proc doesn't return sleeping sessions so if you wanted to log everything, you need to set `@show_sleeping_spids = 2`. More on that is in the [options page.](http://whoisactive.com/docs/06_options/)

Once you log the users / session  /queries from this proc, then you can do the rollup yourself of course.

Answer (score 1):

Glenn Berry (SQL Skills) has done a ton of great work using SQL Servers dynamic managemnet objects. Several of his queries do capture CPU information. You may be able to re-cobble one or more of them to get what you're looking for.
Start by downloading the version appropriate to your environment.
[SQL Server Diagnostic Information Queries for October 2018](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/sql-server-diagnostic-information-queries-for-october-2018/)